# How to wrap netty's ChannelBufferInputStream with InflaterInputStream for inflating data?

Tags: java, inputstream, netty

I am using netty, and have to parse binary data in a ChannelBufferInputStream. Here's the code I am using:

```
ins.skipBytes(14); // skip 14 bytes header
byte[] b = new byte[195]; // note that 195 is the length of data after inflation
(new InflaterInputStream(ins)).read(b, 0, 195);
```

This works as expected, but it sets the mark on the ChannelBufferInputStream after 195 bytes.
Needless to say, the mark should have been set after less that 195 bytes.

Is it possible to get the no. of 'actual' bytes read from the inputstream so that I can set the mark myself? Or is there some other way to inflate a ChannelBuffer's data in netty?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what the larger code flow looks like, it's hard to recommend a best practice, but assuming you're reading an incoming network stream, a better pattern might be to use a sequence of pipeline handlers like:

```
HeaderHandler -->  decoder, returns null until 14 bytes are read
   InflaterDecoder --> Inflates the remainder (will ZLibDecoder work ?)
      AppHandler -->  Receives the inflated buffer
```

But to answer you first question directly, [ChannelBufferInputStream.readBytes()](http://netty.io/3.9/api/org/jboss/netty/buffer/ChannelBufferInputStream.html#readBytes%28%29) will, to quote the javadoc:

> Returns the number of read bytes by this stream so far.